# SQL date column being converted to DT_WSTR instead of DT_DBDATE using SSIS lookup component

Tags: sql-server, date, ssis, type-conversion

I am using a view to use as basis of a Lookup transformation in SSIS.

In my view, I have a couple of columns which is of DATE data type.

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vCampaign] AS 
SELECT 
       CampaignID
      ,CAST([startDate] AS DATE) AS [CampaignStartDate]
      ,CAST([endDate] AS DATE) [CampaignEndDate]
      ,CAST([expirationDate] AS DATE) AS [CampaignExpirationDate]
  FROM campaigns
GO
```

My problem is that those dates show as DT_WSTR in my lookup output columns and not DT_DBDATE. When I use DATETIME rather than DATE, I am getting DT_DBTIMESTAMP which is closer to what I want. I am trying to forgo having to use a derived column for this simple data conversion, am I missing something that would make this work?

Best,

Tribe84

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I fixed it changing the OLE DB Provider from my shared connection.
When I selected "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server" the look up component identified the date column in my SQL SERVER 2014 databse like DT_WSTR. I changed the OLE DB Provider to "SQL Native Client 11.0" and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a very similar error moving data between SAP HANA 2.0 and a SQL Server 2019 in Azure. I was using SSDT in Visual Studio 2019 and changing my connection manager from "Microsoft OLE DB **Provider** for SQL Server" to "Microsoft OLE DB **Driver** for SQL Server" fixed the issue.

I hope this helps others, as VS and SSIS error message descriptions can still be a bit cryptic in v2019. However, I will say that I no longer need to recreate different package objects when I change the data source from one target to another, which is a great time saver to avoid workarounds for these issues with earlier versions of SSIS.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the Look-up and choose "Show Advanced Editor".

Go to `Input and Output Properties` and specify the data-type of the date columns as `DT_DBDATE`.

Comment: I tried that, but I get an error message saying: does not allow setting output column datatype properties.

Comment: Hmm, based on a quick google, it's possible that rebuilding the lookup from scratch might fix the problem.   Otherwise, can you replace the lookup with a combination of a Source Component and a MergeJoin?

Comment: I already tried to recreate the lookup too. Even more curious, I also created a actual table (as opposed to a view) and still the same issue. I have other date columns working as expected using lookups too, so this issue is super weird to me.

Comment: I would look at the xmla of the lookup that doesn't work and compare it to that of one (or more) that does and see if there's a glaring difference.